# SignalR client not reconnecting

Tags: signalr

Having a problem / lack of knowledge with SignalR , I have a Hub client/server and a separate GUI app with intermittently will connect to the hub and send a message. 
I either need the connection to be maintained or to disconnect after the message has been sent.

The problem I run into is that it will always send the first message but then get stuck sending the second message. I am unsure why this is.

```
    public void SignalR_Connect(string message)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://site/signalr");
        IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateProxy("chat");

        Console.WriteLine("Connection state is : " + connection.State.ToString());

            connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to Connect");
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
                }
            }).Wait();

           //Sending message
            myHub.Invoke("Send", message).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error calling send: {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                    Console.WriteLine(task.Status.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Send Complete.");          
                }
            }).Wait();


        //Back round to get the next message.
        //Method grabs next message in the MSMQ and sends it to SignalR_Connect method.
        Read_Queue();
    }
```

I have tried connection.stop() , implementing a close method on the hub to inform the server of the client leaving and setting the GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout but I am still getting the same behaviour.

Comment: What is `Read_Queue();` ? and where is it sending the 2nd message?

Comment: Why do you reconnect each time?

Comment: I did have an IF checking the connection status but it didn't seem to have an affect. How would I maintain the connection and send the messages?.

Comment: Ah Ok , that works much better if i just connect when i start and don't try to disconnect/re-connect every time.